# Thunderbird equivalent to Outlook's 'mark to download messages'

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using thunderbird to download all the pop3 messages with 'download headers only' option enabled, i see option to download the entire message for individual messages but not more than one.

is there any thunderbird equivalent to Outlook's 'mark to download messages', so that i can download more then one message at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select all the messages you wish to download
2. Right-click on one of the selected to bring up the context menu
3. Select **Get Selected Messages** from the menu. It's around the bottom of the list.

You may need to slow your cursor as you go down the list of options in the context menu in order to ungrey the **Get Selected Messages** option.

Comment: Get Selected Messages is disabled for me, even i go through list of options slowly its not enabled, am i missing something?

Comment: Did you pause on the Move option to see if the Get Selected becomes available? @riy

Comment: Yes, in fact i have tried pausing for each menu option but still not working

Comment: Alternatively, there is File > Offline > Get Selected from the file menu. Does that work? @riy

Comment: thanks -random-, though its not exactly i wanted [i don't wanna download few of the big mails], it solved the problem to an extent